# Replacing bytes from start of every function with IDA Pro

Tags: ida, linux, idapython, arm, patch-reversing

I want to fix a .plt segment in IDA Pro by replacing 12 bytes from start of every function in the .plt segment with the ones I specify.

I want to just make each function return so I'm replacing opcodes to do this, but doing this by hand is a painful job. My fingers and palm hurt after I modified a single library, so I need a way to do that with IDA Python.

It's an ARM 32 shared library, I know it doesn't matter here but specified for goodness sake.

This is the hex I'm replacing in every function:

`00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e3 1e ff 2f e1`

This is what this hex is all about:

```
    movs r0, r0
    movs r0, #0
    bx lr
```

Comment: How are you "doing this by hand"?